# Fluid if condition fails to detect image?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I am looping over a list of categories and trying to render an image if it exists.

My problem is the IF condition comes up false. If I remove the condition it will render the image just fine, but it will break the site if there is no image.

```
<f:for each="{categories}" as="cat">
    <f:if condition="{cat.image}"><f:image image="{cat.image}" /></f:if>
    <span>{cat.title}</span>
</f:for>
```

**Edit - A Workaround:**

As this template is an override for a third party extension, I cannot fix the core issue. But I came up with a workaround:

I can use `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.getCatImg" data="{img: cat.image }" />`

Then I created a basic `FLUIDTEMPLATE` in typoscript:

```
lib.getCatImg = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.getCatImg {
    templateName = CatImage
    templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:my_site/Resources/Private/Templates/
}
```

Finally, in the new template I can use `<f:if condition="{data.img}">` and it works as expected. If there is a simpler way, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the code looks good.

Without more information about the category model and the image property, the following is just a hunch.
TYPO3 v9 (and TYPO3 v10) uses Fluid 2.6 and there are [problems with the variables if the property uses a LazyLoadingProxy](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/issues/468).
This problem should be fixed from TYPO3 v11 using Fluid 2.7.

If my assumption is correct there are the following solutions:

1. remove the LazyLoadingProxy in the model for the image property.
2. maybe it helps not to check for `{cat.image}` itself in Fluid but to generate the image URL - so use `{f:uri:image(image:cat.image)}` in the condition.
3. rather in the mid-term but quite recommended: Update to TYPO3 v11.
   [TYPO3 v9 LTS reached its end of free support on 30 September 2021](https://typo3.org/article/typo3-v9-end-of-support-announcement)

Comment: And building on this: avoid `LazyLoadingProxy`, it's not worth using and the performance gain should be negligible. There are better approaches like a custom model per purpose/usage.

Comment: This looks like it. Unfortunately, this is an override template for a third party extention so number 1 is out. Number 3 is not an option sadly. How would you suggest I use the `f:uri` and avoid the no-image error?

Comment: Just like I wrote. Use it in the condition. Should look like this: `<f:if condition="{f:uri:image(image:cat.image)}"><f:image image="{cat.image}" /></f:if>`

Comment: I tried that but it has the same error when there is no image.